# echo asterix at the end of variable in bash

Tags: bash

I have the following script.

```
#!/bin/bash

PHOTOS_DIR=$1
PHOTOS_LIST=$2

while read line           
do
    echo "line: ${line}"
    pattern="*`echo \"$line\" | tr ' ' '*'`*"
    echo "pattern: ${pattern}"
done <$PHOTOS_LIST
```

It gives very weird output. For example:

```
line: 20121224-100 5777
*attern: *20121224-100*5777
line: 20121224-100 5778
*attern: *20121224-100*5778
```

I tried with escaping last asterix character but it does not work as well.

```
line: 20121224-100 5777
\*ttern: *20121224-100*5777
line: 20121224-100 5778
\*ttern: *20121224-100*5778
```

If I try similar thing in bash console it works well:

```
$ line='a b'
$ pattern="*`echo \"$line\" | tr ' ' '*'`*"
$ echo "pattern: ${pattern}"
pattern: *a*b*
```

What is wrong in the script?

---

I did another test. The following works well.

```
for line in "20121224-100 5777" "20121224-100 5778"
do
    echo -e "line: ${line}"
    pattern="*`echo \"$line\" | tr ' ' '*'`*"
    echo -e "pattern: ${pattern}"
done
```

There is something with this `while read line` loop. But what?

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Nice tool. I didn't know it before. I fixed errors but it didn't help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your input file `$PHOTOS_LIST` has CRLF line endings.
Run `dos2unix $PHOTOS_LIST` to change the file for good.

Alternately, try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

PHOTOS_DIR=$1
PHOTOS_LIST=$2

while read line           
do
    echo "line: ${line}"
    pattern="*`echo \"$line\" | tr ' ' '*'`*"
    echo "pattern: ${pattern}"
done < <(tr -d '\n' < $PHOTOS_LIST)
```

Comment: You are right! Actually I found it myself right now. Respect you were able to figure it out just looking at the output!